# Compiling rosbag C++11 APi with just make: error "DSO missing"

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosbag, c++11

[image: Rosanswers logo]

File read.cc contains the rosbag C++11, non-boost, API example for reading a rosbag, enclosed inside main(){...}.

Following lines are in file m:

```
#!/bin/bash
   
gcc  -I/opt/ros/melodic/include read.cc  -c -o foo.o
   
gcc  foo.o \
     -L/opt/ros/melodic/lib \
     -lrosbag \
     -lrosbag_storage \
     -lrostime \
     -o foo.exe
```

Executing `./m` results in:

```
$ ./m
/usr/bin/ld: foo.o: undefined reference to symbol '_ZN3ros6HeaderD1Ev'
/opt/ros/melodic/lib/libcpp_common.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`c++filt` shows:

```
$  c++filt  _ZN3ros6HeaderD1Ev
Ros::Header::~Header()
```

So how can the commands in `m` be modified to result in a successful compilation for the C++API example ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349482/compiling-rosbag-c++11-api-with-just-make:--error-%22dso-missing%22/) by [sg](https://answers.ros.org/users/34175/sg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2020-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A tutorial at [Robotics Back End](https://roboticsbackend.com/ros-node-outside-catkin-workspace/) helped reolve the issue; a `m` file that results in a successful build is:

```
#!/bin/bash
  
gcc -std=c++11 -I/opt/ros/melodic/include read.cc  -c -o foo.o
  
gcc  foo.o \
     -std=c++11   \
     -L/opt/ros/melodic/lib \
     -lrosbag_storage \
     -lrosbag \
     -lrostime \
     -lcpp_common  \
     -lboost_system \
     -lstdc++  \
     -lroscpp_serialization  \
     -o foo.exe
```

---

Originally posted by [sg](https://answers.ros.org/users/34175/sg/) with karma: 26 on 2020-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0